# My Google Docs getting weird in formatting and difficult to edit

Tags: python, google-docs

[Crop of my google docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJzkT.jpg)

So, I don't know what happen to my google docs, but everything went well until I tried to open the ".xlsx" file using openpyxl module in Python
I am not sure as well if it was caused by the module itself or what caused the error in my google docs.

So, basically my google docs is getting difficult to be edited. When i tried to move my cursor at certain points, it always brings the cursor in the beginning of the sentence at particular line. Next if I type something it always appear at the section "IT APPEARS HERE". And last thing, if i type something without a space or enter, it will not type in the new line but it seems like just breaching the page border and goes beyond that. I don't know what is going on here.

I am wondering if it was caused by my trial & error in the python code (?), but seems like no direct correlation between that. So, yeah I need your advice on this guys.. I really appreciate your help

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

`.xlsx` is file format for `Microsoft Excel`, try opening with `Google Sheets`

Comment: No , i m not trying to open the google sheet, but as you can see in the picture above, the display of my google docs become super weird.. I only want to find a way to fix it by the way.. if you know something, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to the issue described here: https://www.androidpolice.com/2021/04/14/if-youre-using-an-ad-blocker-in-google-docs-you-could-run-into-weird-problems/

Basically: Disable your adblocker for google docs for now.

Comment: Thanks a lot Superwayne! Really appreciate your help, had been trying to find a solution for more than 2 hours yesterday.. It works well now, but is it possible if that was caused by running a python program? I am a newbie who tried to make an automation with python so still have shallow understanding about it

Comment: I think it's a change from Google's side that caused the issue. In general, a python program can (as any program) cause problems but as long as you're not using malicious third party code in your application you should be fine.